# Visual Studio 2010 Designer can't find assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0

I am getting the following error in the VS2010 designer:

System.Reflection.Adds.UnresolvedAssemblyException
Type universe cannot resolve assembly: Microsoft.Expression.Interactions, Version=4.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

It is a Silverlight project and the missing assembly is referenced by the project. The project compiles and runs fine.

I looked with fuslogvw and I can't find that error message.

Do I need to copy the dll somewhere where the Designer can find it?

Comment: have you tried to re-reference the assembly? besides, if u r using an external DLL with sample code from examples online .. make sure that u r using the same version of the DLL used in the example

Answer (score 1):

This assembly is part of Blend SDK. You can install it for free from here:
[Microsoft Expression Blend Software Development Kit (SDK) for .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=75e13d71-7c53-4382-9592-6c07c6a00207&displaylang=en).

Comment: Worked for me with a similar problem with a WPF application in Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

If you're using zipped .dll's downloaded from the web under Vista or Win7, the OS *blocking* feature can cause this problem. I wrote up a [blog post last week](http://syncor.blogspot.com/2011/06/wpf-and-ninject.html) about how to unblock prior to unzipping a file. I know it solved a very similar problem I was having with Ninject.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem an finally resolved it in an unusual but successful way.

We are using Blend SDK's `System.Windows.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Expressions.Interactions`.

Everything works fine, unless the designer crashes when using an inherited `DataTrigger` with the same Exception. This would not be the mess, but the exception also breaks IntelliSense in the whole XAML Document, which is not acceptable.

Since this is a reprocducible and reportet error, I decided to solve the problem using disassembling, since we need the extensions to the Interaction Framework.

See: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/648819/visual-studio-2010-silverlight-designer-crash

Simply get a Versions of SharpDevelops ILSpy, and open the two assemblies within it. Select the assembly from the list and go to File -> Save. This will disassemble the whole projects. Integrate those in a blank solution and change the assembly names. Rebuild the reference from the Expression.Interactions library to your new disassembled version.

In the `AssemblyInfo.cs` you can do a trick.

In `Microsoft.Expression.Interactions`:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "i")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Input")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Layout")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Media")]
```

in `System.Windows.Interactivity`:

```
[assembly: XmlnsPrefix("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "i")]
[assembly: XmlnsDefinition("http://yourdomain.com/interactions", "System.Windows.Interactivity")]
```

Now put a reference to the new projects in your assembly, or build the assemblies and copy a version of them to your libraries folder and reference the built versions directly.

In XAML add the new namespace to your rootelement like page/window:

```
<RootElement xmlns:i="http://yourdomain.com/interactions">
    <!-- your xaml code -->
    <i:Interaction.Triggers> ... </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</RootElement>
```

It works like a charm. You can use both interaction and expressions functionality combined into one xmlns and of course, the designer exception is gone and IntelliSense will no longer break.